# Add custom field in group price

Tags: magento-1.9, group-price

I need to add two custom fields in group price both in simple product and in bundle.

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/group.phtml
```

Actually I want to calculate Profit and Profit percentage, 
for example

```
   Price:  144.00
   Profit: 20.00
   Profit Percentage: 13.89
```

I successfully add both in first row as wholesale... but when I add next field it's not working and repeating itself. Would anybody guide me in the right direction?

```
<?php foreach ($this->getValues() as $_item):

$getCost  = $_product->getCost();
$groupprofit = $_item['price'] / 1.2 - $getCost;
$grouppercentage = $groupprofit / sprintf('%.2f', $_item['price']) * 100; 
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>



var groupPriceRowTemplate = '<tr>'
+ '<td<?php if (!$_showWebsite): ?> style="display:none"<?php endif; ?>>'
+ '<select class="<?php echo $_htmlClass; ?> required-entry" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[{{index}}][website_id]" id="group_price_row_{{index}}_website">'
<?php foreach ($this->getWebsites() as $_websiteId => $_info) : ?>
+ '<option value="<?php echo $_websiteId; ?>"><?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->escapeHtml($_info['name'])); ?><?php if (!empty($_info['currency'])) : ?> [<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_info['currency']); ?>]<?php endif; ?></option>'
<?php endforeach; ?>
+ '</select></td>'
+ '<td><select class="<?php echo $_htmlClass; ?> custgroup required-entry" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[{{index}}][cust_group]" id="group_price_row_{{index}}_cust_group">'
<?php foreach ($this->getCustomerGroups() as $_groupId => $_groupName): ?>
+ '<option value="<?php echo $_groupId; ?>"><?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->escapeHtml($_groupName)); ?></option>'
<?php endforeach; ?>
+ '</select></td>'
+ '<td><input class="<?php echo $_htmlClass; ?> required-entry <?php echo $_priceValueValidation; ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[{{index}}][price]" value="{{price}}" id="group_price_row_{{index}}_price" /></td>'


+ '<td><?php echo  sprintf('%.2f', $groupprofit);  ?></td>'  
+ '<td><?php echo  sprintf('%.2f', $grouppercentage); ?> </td>'  


+ '<td class="last"><input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[{{index}}][delete]" class="delete" value="" id="group_price_row_{{index}}_delete" />'
+ '<button title="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete Group Price'); ?>" type="button" class="scalable delete icon-btn delete-product-option" id="group_price_row_{{index}}_delete_button" onclick="return groupPriceControl.deleteItem(event);">'
+ '<span><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'); ?></span></button></td>'
+ '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

All your code needs to be enclosed in the foreach loop.  The following 2 lines we outside the foreach loop, hence it'll only display the last value from the loop.

```
+ '<td><?php echo  sprintf('%.2f', $groupprofit);  ?></td>'  
+ '<td><?php echo  sprintf('%.2f', $grouppercentage); ?> </td>'
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes already try ...but its repeating first field.. if you have any idea how price in curly bracket --- {{price}} -- calculated or how this works...

Comment: Looking further down the template file, 
<?php foreach ($this->getValues() as $_item) : ?>
groupPriceControl.addItem('<?php echo $_item['website_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $_item['cust_group']; ?>', '<?php echo sprintf('%.2f', $_item['price']); ?>', <?php echo (int)!empty($_item['readonly']); ?>);
<?php endforeach; ?>